# Application level variables in web api c#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am in a situation where requirement is to keep an application level object in web api which can be accessed by all requests. I know one can use HttpContext.Current but that is not required since HttpContext is only for the liftime of request. I need a solution where i can keep an object that all requests can access and update as required.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `static` class to hold your application level objects. `static` classes and `static` data members are created once for the application lifetime and all ASP.NET requests can access them.

I learnt it the hard way. Some time back, I mistakenly created a `static` field to hold customer-specific database connection string, in a ASP.NET Web API project and it became a mess. On each customer's login it was being set (overridden) in the code and the requests from the previously logged customers were using this newly set `static` SQL connection string for their queries. It was an embarrassing situation when customer's inadvertently saw each other's data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SessionState (per session).

I.e.

```
Session["YourDataKey"] = ApplicationLevelObject;
```

And then check the session state variable on each request that requires it.

However if you require the object for longer, I.e. every single user session, then I would suggest persisting your object to a database. You could use an ORM such as Entity Framework.

Cheers

Comment: Sessions are request level. Session["YourDataKey"] will remain for for the request only. Where as i want it to be shared among other requests/sessions